# R: How to looping through .Rda files?

Tags: r

I have four(say) .Rda files where each file consists a vector of observations.

I like to compute simple mean vector whose elements computed from different file

```
mean1=array(0,dim=4)
for (i in 1:4){
mean1[i]= mean(readRDS(file = "i-th file "))
}
```

How to do this? I am using simple mean function to illustrate the my point but eventually I will do to more than one things with in a loop after using i-th file.

I read different materials like [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/looping-through-files/) but could not apply it here.

Comment: What do your filenames look like?

Comment: @sebastian-c Here is a file name I am working on "data/2001.Rda"

Comment: Maybe `lapply(list.files(),function(i)mean(readRDS(i)))` ?

Comment: `files <- list.files("data", pattern = "\\.Rda$")` and in `ReadRDS` use `file = files[i]`

Comment: @sebastian-c. After following the suggested line (works fine) but getting error while reading in the file. That is readRDS(file=files[i]) is giving error: cannot open the connection

Comment: What is the value of `i` when the error occurs? What is the value of `files[i]` then?

Comment: @sebastian-c For i=1 , files[i]= "2001.Rda". I am not sure if  "readRDS(file=files[i])" is correct or not for reading files.

Comment: Try adding `full.names = TRUE` to your `list.files` call

Comment: @sebastian-c. Its is working now. Thank you very much. Your suggestion greatly helping me to solve a long standing problem in my code. I got the answer of my question which I found nowhere. I will be happy to accept  your suggestion as answer to my question.

Comment: @Janak The question has been closed, I cannot answer it.

Comment: @sebastian-c.  Though it is now closed, your answer is helpful to my work. Thank you for all your helps.